# Print array in VBA using MsgBox function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I don't usually use VBA but am just trying to double check some values against something, so I would really appreciate some help.

I am trying to create and print an array using the MsgBox function. The array is created and filled inside a for loop which carries out some calculations.

```
Dim NormalLeafDoseVals(0 To 30) As Double
        Dim i As Long
        NormalLeafDoseVals(i) = dCurrRdgI
        i = i + 1
```

So every time the calculation takes place I want to add the new value into this array called NormalLeafDoseVals. Then after the for loop I want to see the whole array so I've put:

```
MsgBox ("Normalised Leaf Dose Values: " & NormalLeafDoseVals())
```

And the error message which comes up says "Type mismatch", and highlights the ampersand before NormalLeafDoseVals().

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use `join`  `msgbox(join(NormalLeafDoseVals,"|"))`

Comment: MsgBox ("Normalised Leaf Dose Values: " & vblf &  join(NormalLeafDoseVals, vblf)

Comment: Do you know how to use the `Immediate`, `Locals` and `Watch` Windows?

Comment: @TinMan no! that sounds like something that could really help! I'll read up on it - cheers

Comment: @EvR hmm now it's subscript out of range

Comment: You should watch this series: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 1 - Getting Started in the VB Editor](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=KHO5NIcZAc4&index=1&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: @Zehrazjp20 don't declare NormalLeafDoseVals as double but as Variant,(or built a string at the same time you fill your array)

Comment: @EvR Thank you so much! Worked a charm :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the declaration to Variant and used the join function:

```
Dim NormalLeafDoseVals(0 To 30) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    NormalLeafDoseVals(i) = dCurrRdgI
    i = i + 1
MsgBox ("Middle Leaf Dose Value: " & dLeaf20RdgI & Chr$(13) & "Normalised Leaf Dose Values: " & vbLf & Join(NormalLeafDoseVals, vbLf))
```